Error Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000
I wrote some code to create a window, but this part that creates an error:
void MakeBitMap(DWORD** window_p) { 
ws_cpy[0] = 0x0000aaff; 
}

it crashes with this error:

Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000

I saw another post and answers were talking about "dereferencing a pointer that hasn't been initialized", but the only dereferenced object I have is "window_p". Makebitmap is used like this:
void Prepare_Screen(HWND hWnd){
    MakeBitMap
}

I really don't know what to do.

That's inside the function. But who is calling the function, and is the argument passed there initialized? And address all zero is an obvious nullptr.

DWORD* ws_cpy = *window_p; makes a copy of a pointer. Can you show us how window_p gets its value? (ws_cpy will not be a copy of the data)

Pepijn, after taking a closer look I guess I never gave Window_p a value other then in the makebitmap function, should I give it a value somewhere else and if so what value should I give it.

Maybe this helps : Read pixels (raw bytes) from an hbitmap without copying?

@DomDaBomb I think you are not fully understanding how functions work. You don't give window_p a value in the MakeBitMap function. window_p is a parameter, it gets a value when you call the MakeBitMap function. There is no way to call MakeBitMap without given the window_p parameter a value, but since you did not show us the code where you call MakeBitMap its hard for anyone to tell what value you give it.

An Access Violation at address 0 means you are accessing memory via a null pointer.
In the code you have shown, an AV when accessing wc_cpy means window_p is pointing at a null pointer. IOW, the caller of MakeBitMap() is doing something along these lines:
DWORD* window_p = nullptr;
MakeBitMap(..., &window_p, ...);

You need to point at valid memory before you can write to it.  So, either the caller needs to allocate memory, eg:
DWORD* window_p = ...; // some allocated memory of sufficient size
...
MakeBitMap(..., &window_p, ...);
...
// free memory pointed at by window_p when done using it...

Or, MakeBitmap() itself should allocate the memory (otherwise, there is no reason to pass in window_p as a DWORD** [pointer to pointer to DWORD] instead of a simpler DWORD* [pointer to DWORD]), eg:
void MakeBitMap(..., DWORD** window_p, ...)
{
    *window_p = ...; // some allocated memory of sufficient size
    ...
}

DWORD* window_p = nullptr;
MakeBitMap(..., &window_p, ...);
...
// free memory pointed at by window_p when done using it...


what would be good memory of sufficient size

However much memory the bitmap requires. You have to calculate that for yourself based on the required dimensions and pixel depth of the bitmap.

thank you but lets say i caluculate the suffecient memory,  how would i give a varible a certain amout of memory. i understand how to give a varible memory using points but that where i stop.

@DomDaBomb I already showed how to do that in the examples of my answer. You already have a pointer, you just need to point it at the allocated memory before you can then write into that memory using that pointer.

im slighly confused, i know I'm suppsed to put it in 0x00 format but what would i put in there to give it memory. sorry for all the questions.

@DomDaBomb are you asking how to allocate memory? Because that is a very different question than the one you originally asked in this post.  Use new[] or std::malloc() or ::LocalAlloc() or any of a dozen other allocation functions that are available.
